# RunTimeError: pdf Latex not install

Tags: python, python-3.x, latex, pdflatex

```
$ schtex drawing.sch drawing.png
```

When I try to run the above code it says that I don't have pidflatex installed even though I have pip installed latex, tex, and pdflatex.
I have also run the following lines when testing another piece of code and it failed to obtain anything:

```
from sympy.utilities.misc import find_executable
find_executable('latex')
```

It also gave me an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/schtex", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/lcapy/scripts/schtex.py", line 231, in main
    cct.draw(label_nodes=args.label_nodes,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/lcapy/netlistmixin.py", line 1624, in draw
    return cct.sch.draw(filename=filename, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/lcapy/schematic.py", line 792, in draw
    self.tikz_draw(filename=filename, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/lcapy/schematic.py", line 597, in tikz_draw
    self.circuitikz_date, self.circuitikz_version = latexrunner.circuitikz_version()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/lcapy/system.py", line 230, in circuitikz_version
    self.run(tex_filename)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/lcapy/system.py", line 183, in run
    checkexe('pdflatex')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/lcapy/system.py", line 68, in checkexe
    raise RuntimeError('%s is not installed' % program)
RuntimeError: pdflatex is not installed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my experience, running these packages require to actually have a LaTeX distribution installed on your computer (which contains `pdflatex`).

I would recommend you using teXlive, which is one of the most common : https://www.tug.org/texlive/

You could also use MikTeX which is also a very common distribution : https://miktex.org/